# In MATLAB ,do the input signals need to be of the same sampling rate for the conv function to work correctly?

Tags: sampling

eg. z=conv(u,v) where u is the input signal encoded in 24KHz sampling rate and v ,the impulse response encoded in 44kHz .
z is played at 24KHz rate .
In the convolution function ,we basically perform a convolution of input and impulse response samples.But reading across the net, I found that for convolution the input and impulse signals must be signals encoded at the same rate.
How true is this?

Answer (score 2):

What an interesting question! An impulse response sequence, taken on its own, does not have a specific numerical sample rate (measured in Hz) associated with it. If I applied a [1, 0, 0, 0, ...] unit impulse sequence to a 3-point moving average lowpass filter then the filter's impulse response would be the sequence [1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 0, 0, 0, ...].  There's no specific numerical sample rate (measured in Hz) associated with either the input unit sample sequence or the filter's impulse response sequence. If you insist on talking about the somewhat unusual notion of the *sample rate of a filter's impulse response* I suppose you can say, "The sample rate of a filter's impulse response is always equal to the filter's input data sample rate."

For example, if to my 3-point lowpass moving average filter I apply an input sequence whose sample rate is 1000 samples/second (1 kHz), then the filter's output sequence has a sample rate of 1000 samples/second. On the other hand, if I apply an input sequence whose sample rate is 24000 samples/second (24 kHz) to the *same* lowpass filter, then the filter's output sequence will have a sample rate of 24000 samples/second. (WARNING: I suggest you never discuss *the sample rate of a filter's impulse response* during a job interview.)

Comment: thanks for responding.By sample rate of the impulse response what I meant was the sample rate at which the response was encoded.So what I understood is ,all it comes down to is samples,not the rate?(i've edited the question a bit)...and yeah I'll heed to your warning :)

Comment: @Richard Lyons I'm not sure but I guess the user wants to ask about applications involving, say, room impulse response equalisation filters. I never practically implemented one, but to obtain an "expected" result back on time domain, both the signal x(t) and room impulse response h(t) should be sampled at the same rate, otherwise filter's effect will be different on the output y(t), due to different frequency scales? am I wrong? Actually it is the sample rate of x[n] which determines the effect of filter such as having a lower cutoff or higher cutoff frequency on the output computation.

Comment: Fat32: The original poster referred to an (1) an input signal and (2) an impulse response, so I assumed he was talkin' about digital filters. But the notion of measured mechanical or acoustic impulse responses never occurred to me. VERY good point Fat32!

Answer (score 2):

A sample rate, in Hz (or samples per second), will determine a relationship between a FIR filter's impulse response, encoded as as vector of elements, and its frequency response with respect to Hz.  If you apply a FIR filter to a signal at a different sample rate then the sample rate at which the filter's frequency response was measured, described or determined, then the filter's effect will be different from one in the frequency response's description.

If you want the impulse response's described frequency response (at a different sample rate) to apply, then you may need to resample either the signal or the impulse response before convolution.